# Escape single curly brace in ansible variable

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible to read the list of RPM's installed on my redhat host and would like to specify a format as well. How can I escape single curly braces in my command string?

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: rpm -qa
    command: rpm -qa --qf "{NAME}: %{VERSION}\n" | sort
    register: rpmout

  - debug:
      msg: Your rpms are {{ rpmout.stdout }}
```

Output from running the above playbook:

```
$ ansible-playbook -vvv ./a.yml 
ansible-playbook 2.7.10
  config file = None
  configured module search path = [u'/home/ansible/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Apr  9 2019, 14:30:50) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]
No config file found; using defaults
/etc/ansible/hosts did not meet host_list requirements, check plugin documentation if this is unexpected
/etc/ansible/hosts did not meet script requirements, check plugin documentation if this is unexpected
Parsed /etc/ansible/hosts inventory source with ini plugin
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  mapping values are not allowed in this context

The error appears to have been in '/home/ansible/a.yml': line 5, column 34, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  - name: rpm -qa
    command: rpm -qa --qf "{NAME}: %{VERSION}\n" | sort
                                 ^ here
```

Comment: Wrap the whole string in single quotes: `command: 'rpm -qa --qf "{NAME}: %{VERSION}\n" | sort'`

Comment: Thanks @zerkms That was easy! I can accept your solution if you post it as a response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To "unconfuse" YAML parser you need to put the whole string in a single quotes:

```
command: 'rpm -qa --qf "{NAME}: %{VERSION}\n" | sort'
```

or if you need a newline character:

```
command: |
    rpm -qa --qf "{NAME}: %{VERSION}
    " | sort
```